# How to use the Model of MVC in a Q&A application?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I have an application that is to help troubleshooting a device. To do this troubleshooting I make suggestions and then ask for user input with a question that they must answer to continue. Depending on the answer I load a new view with a new set of suggestions and question. I am not sure if I understand the Model part of the MVC setup. I have a model that contains suggestions, suggestion_images, questions, answers, ... I also then link the questions to new model objects. I would just like to know if this is considered best practice? Or am I misunderstanding the MVC design scheme?

EDIT: Here is my model overview:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface troubleshootingInfo : NSObject {
    NSString *stepTitle;
    NSString *stepCount;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *imageTitle;
    NSString *descriptionImageLink;
    NSString *questionTitle;
    NSMutableArray *actionsToPerform;
    NSMutableArray *actionsStatus;
    NSMutableArray *actionsImage;
    NSMutableArray *actionImageTitle;
    NSMutableArray *logActions;
    troubleshootingInfo *nextNoObject;
    troubleshootingInfo *nextYesObject;


    // This is to be used with selections
    NSMutableArray *userInputForAction;
}

//perform function on the set values

- (int) setActionRowHieght:(int)actionID; // get row hieght for table cell
- (int) setDescriptionRowHeight; // get row hieght for table cell
- (int) setQuestionTitleHeight; // get row hieght for table header
- (int) actionCount; // the number of actions in the actionsToPerform array
- (BOOL) isAction; // is action set
- (BOOL) isDescription; // is description set
- (BOOL) isQuestion; // is question set
- (BOOL) isActionPerformed:(int)action; // check if action is performed
- (BOOL) isActionImage:(int)action; // check if action has an image
- (NSString *) updateActionPerformed:(int)action;
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

EDIT: fixed the code per suggestions (I think).

My header file now.

```
@interface TroubleshootingInfo : NSObject

// values of the class
@property NSString *stepTitle;
@property NSString *stepCount;
@property NSString *description;
@property NSString *imageTitle;
@property NSString *descriptionImageLink;
@property NSString *questionTitle;
@property NSMutableArray *actionsToPerform;
@property NSMutableArray *actionsStatus;
@property NSMutableArray *actionsImage;
@property NSMutableArray *actionImageTitle;
@property NSMutableArray *logActions;
@property TroubleshootingInfo *nextNoObject;
@property TroubleshootingInfo *nextYesObject;

// This is to be used with selections
@property NSMutableArray *userInputForAction;

//perform function on the set values

- (int) actionCount; // the number of actions in the actionsToPerform array
- (BOOL) hasAction; // is action set
- (BOOL) hasDescription; // is description set
- (BOOL) hasQuestion; // is question set
- (BOOL) isActionPerformed:(int)action; // check if action is performed
- (BOOL) ihasActionImage:(int)action; // check if action has an image
- (NSString *) updateActionPerformed:(int)action;
```

Ok sorry for the confusion. My question is related to hierarchical data models and table views. After reading through Apples documentation I feel I have a better idea of how a complex table should be handled. I believe the class I have featured here actually needs to be apart of a much more complex data model. I will rethink my design. Thank you.

Comment: What have you considered? What sorts of information will your model need to hold and how might you structure it?

Comment: @Kevin I have displayed my custom object that I want to use. I am not sure if this structure is a good idea.

Comment: How exciting, this is like peer reviewing at work! I noticed there is no comments for the class. Maybe adding some comments letting other coders know exactly what it does might help.

Comment: I have tried to narrow down to what I actually was asking. The question was Hierarchy design for a table based app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks *much* more like a `Controller`-style object than a `Model` object. The `Model` in a quiz domain should have absolutely nothing to do with things like row height! The `Model` is the *domain*: questions and answers. *Maybe* "next question" (it depends on whether the choice of next question is determined by the previous answer, as in an adaptive test).

The classic MVC triad is pretty straightforward:

- The `View` reflects the state of the `Model`
- The `Controller` structures and presents the `View` and other `Controllers`
- The `Controller` also tracks the state of the `Model` and can modify the UX and...
- The `Controller` makes requests of the `Model` to modify its state ("Next question")

In iOS, the `View` will typically be subclasses of `UIView`, often which have other `UIView` elements and widgets as members. The `Controller` will be some form of `UIViewController`. The `Model` are in a form appropriate to the domain.

Since you're talking about row heights, I suggest that you read some tutorials about `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you I looked into UITableViewController and actually found Apple docs on hierarchy design for them. [Apple Docs on Table Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a couple adjustments:

Naming: Classnames should be capitalized.

Properties:  The ivars listed between braces can be replaced by properties.  Compilation will generate getters and setters automatically.

Design: The methods that mention UI layout attributes, like rowHeight, do not belong to the model.  The view controller usually concerns itself with this sort of thing (for example, as the datasource for a table view).  Most likely, the code you have in those methods belongs in your view controller.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I forgot to capitalize the class name. For the rowHeight type information: I use this in a tableViewController. I was trying to make a tableViewController that was independent of the data it was displaying, I'll put it back in the controller(which is the idea of model I think). Also is this an acceptable way of keeping track of user response?

Comment: I see what you mean about the table view controller remaining independent of the data.  A better way is to have the model answer something like a "summary" that the vc can put in the table.  The vc can measure the height of that (or number of lines, etc) and still remain data independent. About user responses, you must be referring to "userInputForAction"?  Seems reasonable, if that array ultimately pointed to other nodes in the model, that would makes sense as a network of questions connected by user answers.  But I'd need to know much more about the app to give useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations

- Use a capital letter for class names (`TroubleshootingInfo`).
- Don't use ivars directly, use properties. Properties that should be private (i.e. not used by other classes directly) can go in a `()` category (`@interface TroubleshootingInfo ()` in the .m file.
- The model should not know anything about row heights. That is for the view (and occasionally view controller).
- Your `isAction`, etc. bools sound like they would better be `hasAction` or `isActionSet`, etc. They are asking if the object *has* a property, not if the object *is* that property.

Comment: I see what you mean by the hasAction. This is a good point for readability.